# Waiting for deleting cookies with webdriver?

Tags: cookies, webdriver

I have a question about deleting cookies using webdriver.
Should I create additional code that will wait when deleting cookies is finished or this function will do it for me?

```
driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
```

I meam test will not go to next steps until all cookies will be deleted?

Comment: Yup it will delete all cookies for current domain.

Answer (score 4):

In my tests, the `driver.manage().deleteAllCookies()` is non blocking.
So i got issues that some cookies were deleted in the middle of the test.

So maybe you want to do the `deleteAllCookies()` in a tearDown method,
or you need to wait after the call:

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
try {
  Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how the Application Under Test(AUT) handles the session.Usually when we do 
`driver.quit` (see [here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#quit())) it should close the browser window which automatically closes the session.

If that doesn't happen then the AUT must be handling it in a different way and as you mentioned 
`driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies()` should clear all the cookies.You should also use clear cookies if you are running multiple tests on the same webdriver session, in that case the browser is not closed and hence session is not cleared.

In general, it is good practice to use the logout functionality of the AUT and then use clear cookies or `driver.quit()` as part of test cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

As it's non-blocking, if you're reusing the same browser it can continue onto the next test before all cookies have been cleared, you can poll for the current count and if necessary attempt to clear again:

C#

```
while (_driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies.Count > 0)
{
  driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
  Thread.Sleep(100);
  
}
```