# How to clear browser cookies using Selenium Web Driver and C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

As with the title, how to clear browser cookies using Selenium Web Driver and C#?

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies(); //delete all cookies
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

I tried the above code but it is not deleting the session data.

Comment: i think you are doing good if above not working then plz try to delete cookie on the basis of name

Answer (score 7):

I think the code is :-

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

not

```
driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
```

OR

> *Trial with same firefox profile:*
>
> 1. driver.close();
> 2. driver = new FirefoxDriver(SeleniumObject.firefoxprofile); // Used the profile with which previous session was started.
> 3. driver.get(AppURL);
>
>    - Browser gets closed.
>    - The cookie is getting lost.
>
> *Trial with get(""):*
>
> 1. driver.get("");
> 2. driver.get(AppURL);

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: In the Login page with an organization, user name and password, the URL is automatically taking some other organization name, so thought of deleting the cookies, but it seems to be not working (intermittent)

Comment: It is non blocking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27504358/waiting-for-deleting-cookies-with-webdriver

Comment: Current update: driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();

Answer (score 7):

You can clear cookies with the following:

```
driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
```

Keep in mind that this will only clear cookies from the current domain. We work with some sites on Azure AD. To properly clear the session at the end of my test I run the delete method, navigate to their domain, and run the delete method again.