# How to clear all cookies in ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, cookies, selenium-chromedriver

Dear stackoverflow community,

after numerous attempts i am reaching out to you.

Does anyone know how to clear all cookies in `ChromeDriver` for Chrome Version 72?

I try incognito mode, i try the command

```
Driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
```

i even try to automate `chrome://settings/siteData` but i cannot find the elements because of the shadow DOM...

If anyone has a solution for me i would really appreciate it.

(I know i have to be on the desired page for `DeleteAllCookies` to work, but my page redirects instantly so it does not work...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly duplicate of this question, I think this gonna solve your issue however this question was asked for `FirefoxDriver` : 
[How to clear browser cookies using Selenium Web Driver and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538182/how-to-clear-browser-cookies-using-selenium-web-driver-and-c-sharp)

As a answer on this one, please try following code instead of yours :

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in `ChromeDriver` there is a way to clear all cookies of **all** websites:

```cs
driver.ExecuteChromeCommand("Storage.clearCookies", new Dictionary<string, object>())
```

Answer (score -1):

You can delete cookies based on your requirement as follows:

```
driver.manage().deleteCookie(arg0);  // Delete specific cookie
driver.manage().deleteCookieNamed(arg0); // Delete specific cookie according Name
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();  // Delete all cookies
```

Apart from these try to put thread sleep for 2 seconds before it redirects and then put the above codes or wait for the transition page with "waitfortext" or some similar methods and then clear the cookies.